# How do I use this regular expression to check a value?

Tags: jquery, regex

Im trying to use [Regular Expression to Validate UK Number Plates](https://gist.github.com/danielrbradley/7567269) but Im not sure how, I know a fair chunk of jQuery but I havent dealt with regex before, this is what I have.

```
$('button#headerevalsubmit').click(function(){
    var headcarreg = $('input#headerevalcarreg');
    headcarreg.filter(function() {
        return this.value.match('(?<Current>^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}$)|(?<Prefix>^[A-Z][0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{3}$)|(?<Suffix>^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]$)|(?<DatelessLongNumberPrefix>^[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{1,2}$)|(?<DatelessShortNumberPrefix>^[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{1,3}$)|(?<DatelessLongNumberSuffix>^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,4}$)|(?<DatelessShortNumberSufix>^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,3}$)');
    });

});
```

But I keep getting invalid expression and I dont know why, my goal is to simply check to see if the input of a text box is a valid uk number plate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've just copied that regex from the web somewhere, and it doesn't really look like a regular expression that would be valid in javascript

Comment: I copied it from the Gist just not sure how to use it either in JQuery or Javascript :/

Comment: JS regex does not support named groups. What exactly do you need? If you just remove the groups, you wil get [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/yQNHbX/4). It can be [shrunk a bit](https://regex101.com/r/yQNHbX/3/), but it will just match full strings matching one of the alternatives.You won't be able to differentiate whether it is any specific format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make the pattern compatible with JavaScript regex by removing all the named capturing groups if you are just interested in checking if a  given UK number plate is valid:

```
var uk_plate_number = /^(?:[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z][0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]|[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{1,3}|[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,4}|[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,3})$/;
return uk_plate_number.test(this.value);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQNHbX/3/).

Note that the structure of the regex is changed for this scenario so as the acnhors are not repeated: `^...$|^...$` => `^(?:...|...)$`. The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that makes `^` and `$` apply to each alternative in the alternation group.